# Tag for academia

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

At the moment, Operations Research SE has tag [academic](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic). Since a single adjective a poor name for a tag makes, I propose that the tag be renamed [academia](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academia).